# Develop Vaadin component. Use without upload

Tags: java, maven, components, vaadin8

I want to develop a vaadin component and use it directly in my project without uploading and publishing it to the vaadin directory first. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it work? You can use any class that you have within your project / module

Comment: Nobody can force you to upload your component as an add-on. But if you think other developers could benefit from your component, then publishing it as an add-on is a great way to contribute ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible.

I have two projects in my Eclipse, first is a component project (customtimer), second is a standard Vaadin 8 Web Project (progress-tracker).
[image]
[image]

Step 1. You need to run Maven command to "install" your project to local Maven repository, like this: Right Click "your component project" > Run As > Maven install

Once Step 1 is finished, your component jar is installed in local Maven repository

Step 2. In your Vaadin 8 web project, Right click on project > Maven > Add dependency. In the popup window that opens, type the component project name in the 4th box (screenshot attached), select your component project from the results and click OK. That is it.
[image]

I hope it helps.